# How to configure IIS-8 and its application pool to execute PowerShell/PowerCli scripts inside the hosted Asp.net MVC

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2, powercli

I have the following configuration :

- Windows Server 2012 R2.
- IIS-8.
- ASP.NET MVC-5 web application hosted under IIS-8.

Now my asp.net MVC Web application have a method which execute some PowerShell & PowerCli commands, here is a sample of the scripts:

```
var shell = PowerShell.Create();
var shell2 = PowerShell.Create();
var shell3 = PowerShell.Create();

string PsCmd = "add-pssnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core; $vCenterServer = '" + vCenterName +
  "';$vCenterAdmin = '" + vCenterUsername + "' ;$vCenterPassword = '" + vCenterPassword +
  "';" + System.Environment.NewLine;

PsCmd = PsCmd + "$VIServer = Connect-VIServer -Server $vCenterServer -User $vCenterAdmin `
  -Password $vCenterPassword;" + System.Environment.NewLine;
PsCmd = PsCmd + "Get-VMHost " + System.Environment.NewLine;

// PowerCLI script to the the hypervisor network info
string PsCmd2 = "add-pssnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core; $vCenterServer = '" + vCenterName +
  "';$vCenterAdmin = '" + vCenterUsername + "' ;$vCenterPassword = '" + vCenterPassword +
  "';" + System.Environment.NewLine;

PsCmd2 = PsCmd2 + "$VIServer = Connect-VIServer -Server $vCenterServer -User $vCenterAdmin `
  -Password $vCenterPassword;" + System.Environment.NewLine;
PsCmd2 = PsCmd2 + " Get-VMHost " + vCenterName + "| Get-VMHostNetworkAdapter -VMKernel" +
  System.Environment.NewLine;

shell.Commands.AddScript(PsCmd);
shell2.Commands.AddScript(PsCmd2);

dynamic results = shell.Invoke(); // execute the first PowerCLI script
dynamic results2 = shell2.Invoke(); // execute the second PowerCLI script

// the PowerCLI executed successfully
if (results != null && results.Count > 0 && results[0].BaseObject != null)
```

the problem I am facing is the following :

1. when I deployed the asp.net MVC code which contains the above method on IIS-7 + windows server 2008 R2, everything worked well and the scripts are returned results.
2. but now, on our production server we have IIS-8 + Windows Server 2012 r2, and the above method are not working, the powershell scripts returns null...

Here are the settings I have on IIS-8 :

1. I defined a Domitian user for the DefaultAppPool and I added this domain user to the local admin group on the host server.
2. I also enable anonymous authentication for the web application and I define it to run as the "Application pool identity".

So can anyone adivce why IIS-8 is not allowing the hosted asp.net web application to run powershell scripts ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you try first to execute your PowerShell/PowerCli scripts in the WS2012r2 Server PowerShell Console ?

If so do you use the 32 or 64 bits Console ? Try in each One ?

If so do you consider the target platform of you project to match 64 or 32 bits (the one in wich the scripts works in the Console).

Comment: Yes i tried running the scripts directly inside the Powercli windows and they worked well. i used the 64-bit one , i also tried to target to specific .exe as follow "Start-Process -FilePath C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe; ""  but did not work either .. i have a feeling that this problem s about how IIS-8 versus IIS-7 works,, as on IIS-7 ever thing worked well,, but on production we are using IIS-8 with windows server 2012 R2.. can you adivce more on this please?

Comment: Have you try to target your ASP MVC project 64 bits in spite of ANY CPU.

Comment: can you adivce more on this please ? how i can do so ?

Comment: Give a try : Right Clik on your MVC Project . Then Proprties->generate->Target Plateform x64.

Comment: ok i change the target platform to be x64 and i publish a new web deployment package and deploy it under IIS-8 ,,,now the application will not return any error but still the powershell scripts is not running...

Comment: @JBBlanc can you advice further on this ? and what are the recommended application pool settings in my case ?

Comment: appropriate your efforts already ,, but can you adivce further on this ? thanks..

Comment: Can't you catch exceptions in PowerShell scripts and log onto the disk to see what goes wrong.

Comment: i finally manage to find the cause of this issue. where on the Dev machine (Windows server 2008 R2 +IIS7) i can access the powershell data using something such as results[0].BaseObject.Build while on Live i need to access it using results[0].Build. although on both environments the returned data shown inside visual studio Autos debugging windows is exactly the same ..!! i installed VS on live server to understand the cause !! but i am not 100% sure what is going on ..

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if PowerCLI is installed on the production server. If not, of course `Add-PSSnapin vmware.vimAutomation.core` would fail.

A trivial `string PsCmd` to create an empty file or email could help validate your hunch that the new IIS and PS are not playing nice. (Or at least help put the M in [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a tidier question).

Execution Policy and User Account Control seem unlikely to be breaking this, but I have not tested. Especially if you don't want to handle errors in the code, making a test vm to match production might be worthwhile.